# Is there a way to load standard tab content through custom component

Tags: lightning

Is there a way to load standard tab content like "leads" or "contacts" through custom lightning component? Something similar to the way i can load one custom component in another:
`<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="CustomComponentOneController">
    <c:CustomComponentTwo/>
</aura:component>`

Comment: You cannot bring in standard components which are not exposed for that purpose. But you can always create similar to what is represented in those. What is your goal here?

Comment: Thanks Jayant. I have several custom components with their own tabs with their own styling. If i first click on any custom component tab and then on leads tab my custom styling is loaded and then leads tab inherits it. However if i refresh leads tab my custom styling disapear. Since i cannot otherwise change styling of standard tab i was looking for a way to remove it and load it through basically empty custom component. Rebuilding entire leads functionality into custom component will not work for me due to the huge amount of time it will take. Any other possible solutions? Triggers perhaps?